# normal ssh user@server does not work after setting up config file

Tags: ssh

macOS Sierra 10.12.4, OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0.

My ssh config file is setup as follows (just one of the servers):

```
Host github
    Hostname            github.com
    HostKeyAlias        github
    User                git
    IdentityFile        /Users/abhay/.ssh/github
    IdentitiesOnly      yes
```

When I use `ssh github` at the command line, it works without problem, the correct identity file is used and I'm able to log in.

But if I use `ssh git@github.com`, the config is ignored, and my default identity file `id_rsa` is used instead. This is true for other servers too, not just github.

Is this how it is supposed to work? Sometimes I forget the alias or just prefer to login with complete `user@server` but then ssh fails.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is supposed to work like that.

You can easily overcome this by changing the first line to

```
Host github github.com
```

The reason is that all configurations you do for a `Host` entry are matched to the hostname you give on the command line, and only apply for this name. This makes it possible to have multiple configurations for the same hostname, e.g. with different keys. If there is no match, the default config is used.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Also it works if I add the private key identities to the authentication agent: `$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/github`